# jquery stars hide cancel rating

Tags: jquery-ui

I want to hide the 'cancel rating' option of jQuery stars. How can I do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#stars-wrapper1").stars({
    cancelShow: false
});
```

Answer (score 4):

On page load:

```
$('.rating-cancel').remove()
```

Answer (score 0):

use Firebug to find the location of div-block of 'cancel rating' in the html documentation.
Then delete it or add `style="display:none;"` to the div-block;